# How to create a bitmap with 16 bits per pixel on MacOS?

Tags: c#, image-processing, .net-core, bitmap, imaging

I want to create a bitmap that has 16 bits per pixel, but when I specify any of the pixel formats:

```
PixelFormat.Format16bppArgb1555, PixelFormat.Format16bppGrayScale, PixelFormat.Format16bppRgb555, PixelFormat.Format16bppRgb565
```

They all throw a `System.NotImplementedException` with the error message `"Not Implemented"`. I can't allocate 16 bits per pixel manually because `Bitmap.SetPixel()` only allows you to set a byte to alpha, red, green, or blue (so I need to use marshalling which requires a particular pixel format). Rather than setting a byte for each color value, I'm trying to distribute 16 bits between red, green, and blue. For example 5 bits for red, 5 bits for green, and 5 bits for blue.

Below is an example of one of the 16 bits per pixel pixel formats that throws a `System.NotImplementedException`:

```
Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(width, height, PixelFormat.Format16bppArgb1555);
```

My system is MacOS.

Comment: @mjwills I have image bytes (i.e. bytes representing only an image, no header), and I'm testing to see if the format of the image the image bytes decode to is 16 bits per pixel.

Comment: @harold Are you on MacOS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`System.Drawing` does not support every pixel format on all platforms. Once I [collected](https://docs.kgysoft.net/drawing/?topic=html/M_KGySoft_Drawing_ImageExtensions_ConvertPixelFormat_1.htm) the differences (see the *Restrictions of Possible Pixel Formats on Different Platforms* part). I think MacOS uses the same package as the Linux version.

As `Bitmap` encoders cannot save images preserving the `Format16bppArgb1555` pixel format anyway I suggest you to create a `Bitmap` instance using the closest compatible format (for example, `Format32bppArgb` instead of `Format16bppArgb1555`), and if you really want to transform the colors into the `ARGB1555` color space, you can use the [`Quantize`](https://docs.kgysoft.net/drawing/?topic=html/M_KGySoft_Drawing_BitmapExtensions_Quantize.htm) method with [`PredefinedColorsQuantizer.Argb1555`](https://docs.kgysoft.net/drawing/?topic=html/M_KGySoft_Drawing_Imaging_PredefinedColorsQuantizer_Argb1555.htm) using the same library I linked for the comparison. You can download it from [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/KGySoft.Drawing/).

Disclaimer: I dit not test it on MacOS but it works in Linux (Ubuntu).

> Rather than setting a byte for each color value, I'm trying to distribute 16 bits between red, green, and blue. For example 5 bits for red, 5 bits for green, and 5 bits for blue.

**Edit**: I'm already working on the next version, which will allow using a managed bitmap data with any `PixelFormat` on any platform. See the public  [BitmapDataFactory.CreateBitmapData](https://github.com/koszeggy/KGySoft.Drawing/blob/7c6a9776b2c1469d4ee7d9b98e31ec2b7e27ae92/KGySoft.Drawing/Drawing/Imaging/_BitmapData/BitmapDataFactory.cs#L70) method (not available in a public release yet but you can already play with it if you check out the `Development` branch).

---

**Update:**

> I have image bytes (i.e. bytes representing only an image, no header), and I'm testing to see if the format of the image the image bytes decode to is 16 bits per pixel.

Now I see why you need to set pixels in a 16-bit raw format. As in Linux/MacOS the `System.Drawing.Bitmap` has a limited support the easiest solution if you create managed bitmap data as I mentioned above.

**Note:** I published a [pre-release](https://www.nuget.org/packages/KGySoft.Drawing/5.2.0-alpha.1), which makes the `BitmapDataFactory.CreateBitmapData` method available without checking out my development branch. And now you can turn your raw bytes of any `PixelFormat` to a `Bitmap` like this:

(of course, if `pfGuess` is not the actual format the result can be messy)

```
public Bitmap ToBitmap(byte[] rawData, PixelFormat pfGuess, Size size)
{
    // the result bitmap will be ARGB32, which works on every platform
    Bitmap result = new Bitmap(size.Width, size.Height);

    // we create an accessor for the result so we can quickly copy the translated pixels
    using var bitmapDataDst = result.GetWritableBitmapData();

    // For the managed source any pixel format will work.
    // Please note though that unlike System.Drawing.Bitmap images,
    // managed bitmap data never has padding bytes at the end of each line.
    // So if your rawData has padding (eg. when size has odd width and pf is 16bpp),
    // then maybe the best if you include the padding in width.
    // See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/medfound/image-stride for details
    using var bitmapDataSrc = BitmapDataFactory.CreateBitmapData(size, pfGuess);

    // Checking if rawData is long enough. RowSize is the width in bytes.
    if (rawData.Length < bitmapDataSrc.RowSize * size.Height)
        throw new ArgumentException("rawData is too short");

    int currentByte = 0;

    // iterating through rows
    for (int y = 0; y < size.Height; y++)
    {
        var rowSrc = bitmapDataSrc[y]; // has the specified pixel format
        var rowDst = bitmapDataDst[y]; // has ARGB32 pixel format

        // writing raw pixels
        for (int x = 0; x < bitmapDataSrc.RowSize; x++)
            rowSrc.WriteRaw<byte>(x, rawData[currentByte++]);

        // copying the pixels interpreted as pfGuess to result
        for (int x = 0; x < size.Width; x++)
            rowDst[x] = rowSrc[x];
    }

    // The result bitmap is now populated from the arbitrarily interpreted raw data.
    // As it has ARGB32 format you can save it on any platform without any issues.
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Edit2: sorry, the first link was wrong, now points to the correct page with the comparison table.

Comment: No problem. That's the most detailed, professional, and comprehensive non-microsoft nuget package I've seen, well done. I ran a first test but I'm not sure how to use it. This is what I did: ```Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(width, height); BitmapExtensions.Quantize(bitmap, PredefinedColorsQuantizer.Argb1555());``` The pixelformat property of the Bitmap object was still showing as Format32bppArgb in the debugger, should I expect the pixelformat property to show FormatArg1555? Am I missing any arguments?

Comment: In-place quantizing does not change the pixel format but transforms the colors using a restricted color space or palette. It is more obvious if you use a black-and-white or grayscale quantizer, for example.

Comment: So is the above code the right way to make each pixel 16bpp (may be you can add the code you tested on Ubuntu to your answer)? At the point I perform the quantizing the Bitmap pixels are not colored yet, the coloring is done when I later run `Marshal.Copy()`. Since quantizing transforms the color, should I run the quantization code after the pixels are colored using `Marshal.Copy`?

Comment: On Linux/MacOS you cannot create a `Bitmap` with ARGB1555 pixel format (though you will be able to create any managed bitmap data as I mentioned). So basically you should populate a 32bpp bitmap, and in the end you can quantize it so the colors will be adjusted as if it was a real ARGB1555 bitmap. Actual pixel format will not change, of course. Btw, even in Windows, once you save your 16bpp bitmap by any encoder (eg. PNG), the reloaded bitmap will have 32bpp format so if you want to preserve your 16bpp raw data you need to save it manually. Is this clear or should I still provide an example?

Comment: And instead of the slow `Bitmap.GetPixel/SetPixel` and the memory consuming `Marshal.Copy` you can use a direct accessor as you can see in [this example](https://docs.kgysoft.net/drawing/?topic=html/M_KGySoft_Drawing_BitmapExtensions_GetReadWriteBitmapData.htm)

Comment: Please can you include an example in your answer. Without an example, it is not clear how to use the library, especially since your library has not been tested on MacOS an example would also minimise the room for error from incorrect use. The [page](https://docs.kgysoft.net/drawing/?topic=html/M_KGySoft_Drawing_ImageExtensions_ConvertPixelFormat_1.htm) says *"The SaveAs... members of the ImageExtensions class support saving into any popular format but pixel format will not be preserved."*. Does that mean that when I run `Bitmap.Save()` the image in the image file is not Format16bppRgb555?